# LLVM opt tool does not vectorize IR generated by clang -O0

Tags: llvm, vectorization, llvm-ir

I'm trying to build JIT compiler based on optimization pipeline borrowed from opt tool. 
However I stuck with a problem that my JIT does not vectorize the code. 
I tried to reproduce it with opt on simple example here. https://godbolt.org/z/eRKrLa

In that example clang -O3 emits vectorized IR, however if I try to optimize IR generated by clang -O0 it does not do any changes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think clang -O0 means no optimization

Comment: @droptop yes, I use not optimized IR generated by `clang -O0` and pass it through `opt -O3` expecting that it would optimize it, but no optimizations arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. The output of `clang -O0` is not intended to be re-optimized. You'd need to do something like `clang -O3 -mllvm -disable-llvm-optzns`

Comment: Ok, thanks! But can you tell me what exactly does not allow that code to be optimized? I've added dump of IR generated by my JIT. Maybe you can tell why this IR can not be vectorized?
BTW: loop unrolling works ok for it, but not vectorization.

Comment: @AlekseevArtem are you providing intended target triple to opt as well as cpu? Vectorization needs to know the features of target CPU to work with

Comment: As far as I understand target triple and cpu is a part of `TargetMachine`. I initialize target machine as `createEngineBuilder()->selectTarget()`
I've updated my question with createEngineBuider function. I haven't found any information, does this method provides any default triple and cpu, or how can I get my native triple/cpu?
Very thanks for spending your time on helping me, I appreciate that.

Comment: Oooph, finaly I resolved my issue. My code didn't vectorize because of stupid AddressSpaceCast I inserted instead of PointerCast, as I didn't understand what I do. 
Anyway, thanks, for your help!